# Deploy PowerShell Exchange Cmdlets with site but without installing full Management Instrumentation

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell, exchange-server

Is it possible to run web site for managing Exchange Recipients on a web-server, where only *PowerShell* is installed? I don't want to install full Exchange Management Instrumentation on web-server, I want to use only *Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin* snap-in. Can I use some dll's from Exchange Server bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be (for Powershell V2 - which is supported by Exchange 2007 SP2) to use remoting and configure a session to export the commands you want.

[Register-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819496.aspx) allows you to define commands via a startup script.  There is a great demo of how this works in the PDC 09 sessions [SVR12](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/SVR12) and [SVR13](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/SVR13).  [There are some example scripts in the code samples.](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/11/19/pdc09-svr12-and-svr13-demos-session-demos.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this attempted before, and it failed.  I'm going to assume you're talking about Exchange 2007.

I would recommend looking at using Exchange Web Services.  They have a new managed API that is a relatively small install.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1

Comment: Yes, I think this will be the best way.

Comment: Yes, agreeing with Steven on using PowerShell v2 if you can.  I also remembered the other issue with dependencies when trying to install just a minimal set of DLLs is that Exchange remoting depends on RPC, and from what I can remember, that's implemented in another DLL in another directory...

Comment: I`he read about Exchange Web Services API, and it is not what i want. This API can`t manage the server recipients(create, remove, move to another store ...) , it can just work with messages, calender etc